# what's wrong with this function call about my bind implementation?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to implement `std::bind`(my own `namespase` is `glgltinySTL`).

so my code is as you can see in the second gist link. There are `make_args()` and `call_helper()`

```
template <typename... BArgs, typename... Args, size_t... Is> inline
auto make_args(tuple<BArgs&&...> bind_args,
               tuple<Args...>& args, index_holder<Is...>) noexcept
    -> decltype(forward_as_tuple
                (replace_place_holder
                 <min_place_holder_t<Args>::value,
                  static_cast<bool>(
                    is_placeholder<decltype(get<Is>(args))>::value)//!gcc exit here
                 >::foo(move(bind_args), get<Is>(args))...))
{
    constexpr int MIN = min_place_holder_t<Args...>::value;
    return forward_as_tuple(replace_place_holder<MIN, static_cast<bool>(
                                is_placeholder<
                                    decltype(get<Is>(args))
                                >::value)
                            >::foo(move(bind_args), get<Is>(args))...);
}

template <typename F, typename... BArgs, typename... Args, size_t... Is> inline
auto call_helper(F &&f, tuple<BArgs&&...> bind_args,
                 tuple<Args...>& args, index_holder<Is...> ih)
    noexcept(noexcept(f(get<Is>
                        (make_args(move(bind_args), args, ih))...)))
    -> decltype(f(get<Is>(make_args(move(bind_args), args, ih))...))
{
    auto a = make_args(move(bind_args), args, ih);
    return f(get<Is>(move(a))...);
}
```

and then I did some tests as you can see in the second gist link (from line 1400 to 1403).

It works well under gcc5.2.0.

So I started to test if it works well with member function.

```
auto bm = glgltinySTL::bind(&callable_t::foo, _6, 5, 6ul, _5);
bm('c', &c);
```

And then, I got some strange errors as follows.

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5dfca64265406898073d

So, I started to test `make_args()`.

```
auto a = glgltinySTL::make_tuple(_6, 5, 6ul, _5);
auto tm = glgltinySTL::BIND_HELPER::make_args(
            glgltinySTL::forward_as_tuple('c', &c), a,
            glgltinySTL::index_holder<0, 1, 2, 3>());
```

And then, gcc shows that "不能从先前的错误中恢复，退出(Can not recover from previous mistakes, exit)".

Then I tested follows as `make_args()` do (from line 1420 to 1440).

It works well.

So, my question is that what's wrong with this function call?

Here is that source file, I add some `inline namespace` to make other things foldable.

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/973110af6a6edc186394

After these, I find there is another way to write `make_args()` and `call_helper()`.

```
template <typename... BArgs, typename... Args, size_t... Is> constexpr
auto make_args(tuple<BArgs&&...> bind_args,
               tuple<Args...>& args, index_holder<Is...>) noexcept
    -> decltype(forward_as_tuple
                (replace_place_holder
                 <min_place_holder_t<Args>::value,
                    is_placeholder<decltype(get<Is>(args))>::value
                 >::foo(move(bind_args), get<Is>(args))...));

template <typename F, typename... BArgs, typename... Args, size_t... Is> inline
auto call_helper(F &&f, tuple<BArgs&&...> bind_args,
                 tuple<Args...>& args, index_holder<Is...> ih)
    noexcept(noexcept(f(get<Is>(
        declval<decltype(make_args(move(bind_args), args, ih))>()
                                )...)))
    -> decltype(f(get<Is>(
        declval<decltype(make_args(move(bind_args), args, ih))>()
                          )...))
{
    constexpr int MIN = min_place_holder_t<Args...>::value;
    auto a = forward_as_tuple(
        replace_place_holder<
            MIN, is_placeholder<decltype(get<Is>(args))>::value
        >::foo(move(bind_args), get<Is>(args))...);
    return f(get<Is>(move(a))...);
}
```

Gcc will show the the same error, but not exit.

Comment: Whenever gcc claims, that it can not recover from previous mistakes, it should also have told you about the previous mistakes before as well. Please add the relevant error messages. Please minimize your code examples. Remove uninteresting noise as much as possible and just get to the point of your question.

Comment: what is `place_holder`, `index_holder`, `function_type` ... ?

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki `place_holder` is the type of `_1`, `index_holder` is an empty constexpr struct with `template<size_t...>`, `function_type` includes `result_type`, `argument_type` and so on.

Comment: @cdonat Thanks, I have updated.

Comment: Given - that is ambitious thing you try there; my respect. That's why I don't just think [TLDR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Too_long;_didn%27t_read) and skip it. But it at least needs to be compilable without the failing tests; you see?

Comment: But anyway - my nose tells me that you may have to SFINAE the plain bind away for mem_funs; but I'm not sure yet.

Comment: @decltype_auto Thanks, this's the first time I hear SFINAE.

Comment: Sorry; [cppreference.com has basic info about SFINAE](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae). Of course, Bjarne Stroustrup and other core authors explain that in great detail.

Comment: @decltype_auto Thanks, I have made ​​a preliminary understanding via Google, and you don't need to apologize, because that you let me know a new thing.

Comment: have you completed the code posted to make it compilable (skip the failing test, of course) yet?

Comment: @decltype_auto You mean a source file ? I am sorry that i didn't understand your words well. I will give it later because it's time to sleep in my country.

Comment: last time I copied and pasted that into my IDE, compilation died on a huge  bunch of errors, nota bene without the critical test case.

Comment: @decltype_auto Now here is a single source file including all things.